# How to use existing resources from another resource group to make deployments in new resource group using Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform0.12+

I want to create resources in a new resource group but i want to use a virtual network for those resources which is in another resource group. How do i do this? For example, i want to create redis/postgresql in resourcegroupA but i want to make use of the virtual network which is in resourcegroupB. Is it possible?

This is the resource group from where i am retrieving the vnet-

```
    resource "azurerm_resource_group" "azresourcegroup" {
      name        = 
      "resourcegroupA"
      location    = var.resource_group_location
    }

    #-----CREATING VIRTUAL NETWORK-----

    resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet2" {
       name                = "virtualnetworkA"
       location            = azurerm_resource_group.azresourcegroup.location
       resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.azresourcegroup.name
       address_space       = [var.virtual_network_address_prefix_infra,var.virtual_network_address_prefix]
```

I retrieved it while using it for another resource group like this-

```
    data "azurerm_resource_group" "azresourcegroup" {
      name        = "resoucegroupA"
    }

    data "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet2" {
     name                = "virtualnetworkA"
      resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.azresourcegroup.name
    }
```

I want to use the above virtual network but want to create the other resources in the new resource group which is-

```
     resource "azurerm_resource_group" "main" {
      name        = "resourcegroupB"
      location    = var.resource_group_location
    }
```

I am making use of module to create redis cache that requires the vnet which is created in other RG-

```
    module "rediscache" {
      source                             = "../../modules/rediscache"
      prefix                             = var.prefix
      environmentType                    = var.environmentType
      virtual_network_name               = var.virtual_network_name
      unique_identifier                  = var.unique_identifier_kube
      resource_group_name                = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
      resource_group_location            = var.resource_group_location
      redis_subnet_address_prefix        = var.redis_subnet_address_prefix
      azurerm_virtual_network_name       = data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet2.name
      azurerm_log_analytics_workspace_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.workspace.id
    }
```

To simplify this, vnet is created in other resource group and redis in another one.But i want to use that vnet. also if i change the `resource group name` argument used in module, from `azurerm_resource_group.main.name` to `data.azurerm_resource_group.azresourcegroup.name` then it creates the redis in the 1st resource group which i dont want.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, it's possible. The only condition is that the virtual network should be in the same location. Then you can quote it in the Terraform code via the Terraform [Data Source `azurerm_virtual_network`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/d/virtual_network.html) like this:

```
data "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "production"
  resource_group_name = "networking"
}
```

Comment: what if i am making use of modules here?

Comment: @SiddhiMorajkar Of course Yes. The Data Source for the Vnet just help you quote the existing Vnet, it doesn't affect where you want to use it. So you can input its value in the module. The module creates another Redis because you create the resource Redis in it. You just need to use the Data Source for it in the module.

Comment: Can you post an example code just to make it clear?

Comment: @SiddhiMorajkar You need to provide your module code then I can show you how to do it.

Comment: I have provided the module above.

Comment: @SiddhiMorajkar Not the module block. I mean the whole module code, it's the source, not the block.